# Calculating Sums Of Mathss

Tags: classical-mechanics

I'm supposed to use my previous answers to work out the direction of the equilibrant.

My previous resultant magnitude and direction are as follow:

magnitude: $20.87$
direction: $56.21°$

As far as I'm aware the equilibrant has the same magnitude.

By doing this, am I answering the question:  state equilibrant’s magnitude and direction or am I missing something here? Thank you

Comment: As a suggestion, for this kind of problem you could ask all the questions in a single OP since they are stricktly related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes of course that's correct, if we are referring to a $x-y$ system the equilibrant has direction opposite that is exactly $180°-18.7°=161.3°$ and same magnitude.

Comment: This is exactly what I thought. I thought I was going crazy for a second there. Thanks for the reassurance.

Comment: @Maths You are welcome! Bye